# Tensorflow code not running when computer is idle

Tags: tensorflow

I have kept a tensorflow model for run throughout night, but in the morning i see that the tensorflow code did not run even when the laptop is active.

can some one please help on how do i make the tensorflow code running when i am away laptop

Comment: Are you running it on your local machine or on a server such as Google-Colab?

Comment: I am running on local machine. apparently, it is command line issue as tensorflow logs to command line, it gets logged to buffere due to inactivity and if the buffer spills, it halts the programme and resumes after "enter" is pressed.